# C++ Design question: Nested classes (structs) and "parent" references

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes

I'm in the following situation

```
struct Outer {
    CertainObject_t CertainObject;
    ...
    struct Inner {
        some_t some_function() {function involving Outer::CertainObject};
        ...
    };
    std::vector<Inner> vInner;
    other_t other_function() {something that call vInner[i].some_function};
    ...
};
```

Now when I create `Outer` struct and `vInner` is populated (for instance in the `Outer`'s constructor), one can call `Inner::some_function()` from inside `Outer`. This function uses `CertainObject` which is defined in the `Outer`, and so it is visible from `Inner` (it may be a function object, for instance).

I was thinking that perhaps this design looks a bit cumbersome and so I tried to extract `Inner` class and define it *outside* `Outer`:

```
struct Inner;

struct Outer {
    CertainObject_t CertainObject;
    std::vector<Inner> vInner;
    ...
    other_t other_function() {something that call vInner[i].some_function};
};

struct Inner {
    Outer& parent; // I added this (see below)
    some_t some_function() {function involving parent.CertainObject};
    ...
}
```

In this way I needed to introduce `Outer& parent` since every instance of `Inner` has to know to which instance of `Outer` it has to call `CertainObject` from. In the design above, instead, I did not need this.
Of course adding a reference in a struct has a little impact on the memory requirements, and so one can do it painlessly.

Another thing that one can do is to transform `Inner` method `some_function` to a `Outer` method acting on the `Inner` struct.

However I'm baffled about each of these designs. Can you give me some suggestion? Given that I do not need `Outer` class outside `Inner`, can this be a situation where nested classes (or structs) are a good solution? Would you have a more elegant design solution to such situation?

Comment: `In the design above, instead, I did not need this. `: Why? Don't you need `Outer& Inner::parent` anyways to access `certainObject` unless I'm completely missing something? To quote cppreference: `Like any member of its enclosing class, the nested class has access to all names (private, protected, etc) to which the enclosing class has access, but it is otherwise independent and has no special access to the this pointer of the enclosing class.`

Comment: It is by the way, at least in my experience, pretty common to have inner classes that accept a pointer to their "parent" in the ctor.

Comment: nested classes often come with some false expectations. Imho it is best to see them as a way of defining something on the narrowest scope possible, rather than as establishing some relationship between two classes. It is the definitions that are nested, not the objects, hence for `some_t some_function() {function involving Outer::CertainObject};` the Inner class needs an object of `Outer` just as if it would be not an inner class

Comment: the question would be more clear if you could turn the code into a [mcve]. I think not much more code is needed, but code is much easier to understand than a description of the code.

Comment: and anyhow, asking for some suggeststion is opinion-based

Comment: In Java, defining one class inside another implicitly adds such a parent reference (unless the *class* is declared `static`).  This question sounds like you think C++ does this, but it doesn’t.

Comment: *"This function [`Inner::some_function()`] uses `CertainObject` which is defined in the `Outer`, and so it is visible from `Inner`*" -- I challenge you to produce an example of this; produce code where `Inner::some_function()` **uses** (not just sees, but uses) `CertainObject` without a reference or pointer to an `Outer` object.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise, and I see no benefit to speculating what the implications of that premise would be if it was true.